# How do I get the Id of artworkrequests table instead of the id of the table where I join with

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

artworkcontroller:

`$leads = Artworkrequest::join('artworks', 'artwork_id', '=', 'artworks.id')->where('artworks.user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();`

What I want to do is delete the Artworkrequest by passing the {{$lead->id}} but the problem is that it is selecting the id of the table artworks instead of the id of artworkrequest. How can I pass the id of artworkrequest in my blade?

leads.blade.php:

```
@foreach($leads as $lead)
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                <img src="{{ asset('uploads/artworks') }}/{{$lead->picture }}" width="100px" style="width: 100px" alt="">
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ $lead->title }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{ route('lead.view', [$lead->user_id]) }}"><button class="btn btn-dark">bekijk contactgegevens</button></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{ route('delete.lead', [$lead->id])}}"><button class="btn btn-success">Delete</button></a>

                                </td>
                                <td>        
                                    <form action="{{ route('lead.delete') }}" method="POST">
                                    @csrf
                                    
                                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$lead->id}}">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">delete</button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
public function lead()
    {
        $user = auth()->user()->id;
        $leads = Artworkrequest::with('artwork', 'profile')->get();
        return view('artworks.leads', compact('leads'));
    }
```

and blade.php:

```
                        @foreach($leads as $lead)
                        @if(Auth::user()->id == $lead->artwork->user_id )
                        <tr>
                           {{$lead->artwork->user_id }}
                           {{ $lead->id }}

                           {{ $lead->artwork_id }}
                           {{ $lead->user_id }}
                           <td>
                           {{ $lead->artwork->title }} 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                           {{ $lead->profile->first_name }}


                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td>        
                                <form action="{{ route('lead.delete') }}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$lead->id}}">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">delete</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endif

                        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

For this example, why don't you use Eloquent Relation instead of join?

To Do eloquent relationship you have to define the relationships in respective model.

Artwork.php

```
class Artwork extends Model
{

    public function artworkRequest()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ArworkRequest::class);
    }
}
```

ArtworkRequest.php

```
class ArtworkRequest extends Model
{

    public function artwork()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ArworkRequest::class);
    }
}
```

Then in ArtworkController.php you can get the data this way. You don't have to include the `with('artwork')` if you don't need artwork data too.

```
$leads = ArtworkRequest::with('artwork')->whereHas('artwork', function($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
})->get();
```

Then in blade file you can call it with

```
@foreach($leads as $lead)
{{ $lead->id }}

// additionally, you can also call Artwork data by using
{{ $lead->artwork->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can I do this as well ```$leads = Artworkrequest::with('profiles')->with('artworks')->get();``` And then @foreach($leads as $lead (kind of where or if statement?) ) {{ $lead->artworks->title }} {{ $lead->profiles->email }} @endforeach ?

Comment: Yes. It's neater if you just do `$leads = Artworkrequest::with('profiles', 'artworks)->get();` instead of 2 with.

Comment: Controller:  ```public function lead()
    {
        $user = auth()->user()->id;
        $leads = Artworkrequest::with('artwork', 'profile')->get();
        return view('artworks.leads', compact('leads'));
    }  ```

Comment: Thanks. I will post another problem. Because I can access the $lead->artwork->name etc but not $lead->profile->name

Comment: @GijsMachielsen you need to set the eloquent relation for the profile with artworks too. then you can use it that way.